# What is the error in this circuit design?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

Could anyone help me identify the error in this circuit?

[image]

Comment: What is the circuit supposed to do?

Comment: what is the problem with the circuit?

Comment: Are your resistors being shorted out along the same vertical socket group??? Try moving the top connection of each resistor and each + dip switch wire one socket left.

Comment: Draw out your design in standard schematic format, add that new drawing here. (Note that there is a schematic editor available in this forum). If your schematic design seems to make sense next compare it very carefully to your Fritzing layout. Pay particular attention to the common vertical connections in the breadboard system. In your actual physical layout recheck that the LEDs are also in the correct polarity.

Comment: Does your board have red and blue stripes that go the whole length or is there a small gap in the middle?

Comment: @CristhianSelbach - Please add some additional details and/or clarity to your question as requested in the comments. I'll then vote to reopen this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my first comment above is correct and the resistors are being shorted, the coin battery is being connected directly to each LED, (with no current limiting). The enabled LED will draw a high current from the battery. Depending on the actual battery type used there may or may not be enough current to burn out the LED. If you try connecting more than one LED using the DIP switch the LED that has the lower Vf will sink most of the battery current and the other LEDs may not light at all.

In the edited drawing below the large red arrows show where the shorts seem to be. The black X shows where to disconnect the wires from. The added red lines show the new connections for the wires and resistor leads.

Be sure to check the polarity of the LEDs in the actual circuit. Also be sure you have the correct +/- wire connections on the battery holder, the Fritzing drawing may not be showing that properly.

Lastly, using 470 ohm resistors for all the LEDs will likely leave the blue and green LEDs quite dim. You might switch to lower value resistors at least for those two LEDs.

[image]

Comment: Jumpers may be needed to bridge the power rail gaps.

Comment: There are some breadboard types with split power rails, but those will usually have the red or blue lines split to mark the open point.  This one (at least as shown) has the lines solid from end to end. So at least the Fritzing software is assuming complete power rails end to end. @CristhianSelbach - a picture of the physical breadboard would be needed to confirm this idea. Also as commented by Jasen .

Comment: Examples of different breadboard types, with and without continuous power rails located at the sides:   1) https://www.eleinmec.com/article.asp?10     2) https://learn.adafruit.com/breadboards-for-beginners?view=all